# GASのV8 runtimeでHtmlService.getUserAgent()が使えない

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-6

GASでV8 runtimeが使用可能になりました。
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime?hl=ja

しかし、HtmlService.getUserAgent()関数を呼ぶと、レガシーのRhinoエンジンでは使用中のブラウザ情報が返っていましたが、V8エンジンではnullが返るようです。
これを修正、または回避する方法はあるでしょうか。

```
function baz() {
  var foo = HtmlService.getUserAgent();  
  Logger.log(foo);
  return 1;
}
```

上のコードをRhinoエンジンで実行すると、V8では「null」が表示されます。

Answer (score 0):

いいことなのか分からないのですが、英語版でも質問し、一応の解決を見ました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146774/gas-htmlservice-getuseragent-returns-null-when-using-v8?noredirect=1#comment106391217_60146774

要旨としては、V8はGASのHtmlService.getUserAgent()をまだ使えないようだ、代わりにクライアントサイドのJavaScriptでNavigatorインターフェイスを使えば使える、というものでした。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Navigator

GASのWebAppsでも動作し、いちおう目的を達成しました。

また、GoogleのIssueTrackerにも起票すべきというコメントもいただき、そちらも起票しました。
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149247107

以上です。